# How can I prove that $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x_{n}^{3/2}}\right)^{-1}=\frac{3}{2}$ if $x_{n}=x_{n-1}+\sqrt{x_{n-1}}+1, x_{0}=1$?

Tags: roots, infinite-product

If
$$x_{n}=x_{n-1}+\sqrt{x_{n-1}}+1, x_{0}=1$$
so we can say, that
$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x_{n}^{3/2}}\right)^{-1}=\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{3/2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(4+\sqrt{3})^{3/2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(5+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{3}})^{3/2}}\right)\cdots\right]^{-1}=\frac{3}{2}$$
All square roots are positive.

How can I prove it?

Comment: Why do you think that's true?

Comment: I calculate this result in excel and I can say with confidence, that it's true. But why? If I made some mistakes, sorry for my English.

Comment: Ah, numerical evidence, that's good. Let's look for a proof, then.

Comment: What context does this problem arise from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $u_n = \sqrt{x_n}$, we have

$$u_n^2 = u_{n-1}^2 + u_{n-1} + 1 = \frac{u_{n-1}^3 - 1}{u_{n-1} - 1}
\implies u_{n-1}^3-1 = u_n^2(u_{n-1}-1)
$$
This leads to

$$1 - \frac{1}{x_n^{3/2}} 
= \frac{u_n^3-1}{u_n^3} 
= \frac{u_{n+1}^2(u_n-1)}{u_n^3}
= \frac{u_{n+1}^2(u_n^2-1)}{u_n^3(u_n+1)}
= \frac{u_{n+1}^2(u_n^2-1)}{u_n^2(u_{n+1}^2-1)}\\
= \left.\frac{x_n - 1}{x_n}\right/\frac{x_{n+1}-1}{x_{n+1}}
$$
The product at hand is a telescoping one with partial products

$$\prod_{n=1}^p \left(1 - \frac{1}{x_n^{3/2}}\right)^{-1}
=\left.\frac{x_1}{x_1 - 1}\right/\frac{x_{p+1}}{x_{p+1}-1}$$

Since $x_n = x_{n-1}+\sqrt{x_{n-1}} + 1 \ge x_{n-1} + 1$ and $x_0 = 1$, we can show $x_n \ge n + 1$ by induction. This means $$\lim\limits_{p\to\infty} x_p = \infty \implies \lim\limits_{p\to\infty}\frac{x_{p+1}}{x_{p+1}-1} = 1$$
As a result,
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{1}{x_n^{3/2}}\right)^{-1} = \frac{x_1}{x_1 - 1} = \frac{3}{3-1} = \frac32$$

Comment: How do you know that $u_{n-1}^2+u_{n-1}+1 = \frac{u_{n-1}^3-1}{u_{n-1}-1}$?

Comment: @Mark This is the special case for the $t^m - 1 = (t-1)(t^{m-1} + t^{m-2} + \cdots  + t+1)$ when $m = 3$.

Comment: Nice solution, for sure ! Just out of curiosity : what does mean the result given by WA if you just give the initial recurrence relation ? I don't understand this $x_n=(n\pm 1)^2$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it is simply a bug of WA. I'm not surprised.

Comment: It seems to be a **big bug** . If you have Mathematica, could you check if it spits the same (what we can expect) ? Thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Many years ago when I try to purchase Mathematica, I give up b/c its outrageous price outside academia. It is worser now. I don't even know how to get a home edition in my country.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (I fully agree with your statements). May be, someone here will tell us. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Mathematica: RSolve[{x[n] == x[n - 1] + Sqrt[x[n - 1]] + 1, x[0] == 1}, x[n], n] results in $$\left\{\left\{x(n)\to (n-1)^2\right\},\left\{x(n)\to (n+1)^2\right\}\right\}$$ Mathematica now has a home version for around US $250, which also allows a copy on two computers for personal use.

Comment: @Moo thanks for the info. $250 isn't cheap but at least it isn't something completely ridiculous.

Comment: @achillehui: I really enjoy reading your answers and agree, that is a lot of money and I cringe every time I have to pay it! Having said that, the professional version is around $10x$ that, but I think Maple and others are around the same magnitude in cost. Maybe things like SAGE, MAXIMA, ... are also useful.

Comment: @Moo. Thanks for  confirming the strange result.